# Ubuntu 10.10 stop working at login screen after power loss during upgrade

Tags: 10.10, installation, boot, upgrade

I have ubuntu 10.10 and I was upgrading it when suddenly my computer turned off due to fluctuation of power. Now when i am booting my ubuntu then it stops working at  login screen. nothings happen at screen even mouse doesnot work there. I tried it to boot from recovery mode but some code comes on the screen and nothing happens. How can i recover from this problem .

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once before.

You are going to want to use your Live Disc and boot into it. From here, chroot into your partition with the broken install. (If you don't know how to chroot, go ahead and ask me in a comment: I'll be more than happy to help.)

Then, you want to run the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If that doesn't help, let me know.

And, for reference: Were you upgrading the version or just a general software update?